# Making Grails logback format equal to default Spring Boot format

Tags: grails, spring-boot, logback

In order to make our logging formats equal (between Grails & Spring Boot applications) I am looking for a way to let Grails use the same log format as Spring Boot uses.

Does anyone have an example how to configure Grails to use the default logback format from Spring Boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Following patterns can be used in logback.groovy to make log output in Grails similar to Spring Boot applications.

```
pattern = '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} ' +   // date
          '%5p ' +                           // loglevel
          '%property{PID} ' +                // PID
          '--- [%15.15t] ' +                 // thread
          '%-40.40logger{39} : ' +           // logger
          '%m%n'
```